# Course on Moodle - how to download all student interactions?

Tags: teaching, online-learning

My institution uses Moodle as online learning platform. I am enthusiastic at Moodle capabilities, and suspect this had a positive effect on my class. Would like to prove it (or disprove it) by looking at all possible ways students interact with the platform. My understanding is that Moodle stores internally its data through a database powered by MongoDB. Anybody knows how to access that database directly? Would like to avoid having to gather all independent data piecs from separate GUI clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those with admin privileges in moodle they can access the log features to see anybody's activity in moodle. For a teacher this feature is available to see student activity at the course level only. The activity can be  viewed by student and or by the activity selected (forum, assignment, etc). The information provided isn't very deep. Just a time stamp with the student and what they did. However aggregating this info can provide some insights.

Answer (score 2):

After logging into your Moodle account, choose on the course you wish to download data. Click on the Gear icon to the top right, you will find 'Backup'-> now you can check all the student data and download to your local drive. Use the same menu to import the backed-up file for future use.
Refer to [Course Backup](https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Course_backup)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see the way the interactions are done to your course, you will find the log that Moodle generates informative. 
Just go to the gear icon for the course of choice and view the logs.  Filter the same to your requirement.
If you export the logs to a spreadsheet, much greater analytics can be got.

Best Wishes, JSP

Answer (score -1):

There is a really cool way of working out in this regard.
Please check https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Configurable_reports

Dabbling around with just a little, you will be able to do it easily.
Do let me know if you need additional help.   Initially, it is a little frustrating.  But after you get the hang of it, it is a piece of cake.

Knowledge of SQL is important.

Best Wishes,
JSP